# how do perform menu list selection in web application using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation, uiautomation

I am trying to select/navigate to a menu item in the provided URL. I tried Actions but It was not working.

https://enterprise-demo.orangehrmlive.com/auth/login

**uid/pwd : admin/admin**

I wanted to select a menu navigation (e.g: Admin->User Management->User Roles)

```
By admin = By.id("menu_admin_viewAdminModule");
By uMgmt = By.id("menu_admin_UserManagement");
By uRoles = By.id("menu_admin_viewUserRoles");
By username = By.id("searchSystemUser_userName");
By search = By.id("searchBtn");

WebDriver driver2 = driver;
Actions act = new Actions(driver2);

WebElement wadmin = driver2.findElement(admin);
WebElement wusermgmt = driver2.findElement(uMgmt);
WebElement wuserroles = driver2.findElement(uRoles);

act.moveToElement(wadmin).moveToElement(wusermgmt).moveToElement(wuserroles).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Actions API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) for that, given that the browser you use supports it. The following should do the trick with Chrome:

1. Moves the mouse over the "Admin" button
2. Waits until the "User Management" button is visible
3. Moves the mouse over the "User Management" button
4. Waits until the "Users" button is visible
5. Clicks the "Users" button:

### Java

```
WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[contains(., 'Admin')]"));

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(admin).perform();

WebElement userManagement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("menu_admin_UserManagement")));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(userManagement).perform();

WebElement users = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("menu_admin_viewSystemUsers")));
users.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this by using `linkText` or `partialLinkText`:

```
// System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "yourChromeLocation\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://enterprise-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("Admin");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();

WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[contains(., 'Admin')]"));

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(admin).perform();

WebElement userManagement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("menu_admin_UserManagement")));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(userManagement).perform();
//driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("User Roles")).click();

WebElement users = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("User Roles")));
users.click();
```

Comment: Thanks  @Sean Das, In the Above question I tried sequence of Action elements like act.moveToElement(wadmin).moveToElement(wusermgmt).moveToElement(wuserroles).perform()  does this work? or after every action we need to do build().perform() ??